# How to show unicode characters in GAE log console

Tags: google-app-engine

Anybody knows if is possible configure the GAE local developing server to show unicode characters in the log console window?
I mean when you use `logging.info()` function.

Comment: What are you doing now and what are the results?  Give us an example.

Comment: I'm using Python. A when I wrote logging.info('Módulo encontrado'), I get in the log console: INFO     2015-01-12 11:25:10,569 main.py:4011] MÃ³dulo encontrado

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
logging.info(u'Módulo encontrado')
```

The `u` at the beginning indicates that the text in quotes is in the unicode format.  Character encoding is a complicated subject (much more so than people expect) so if you have to handle non-ascii characters it is a good investment of your time to do some intensive reading and learning.

UPDATE:

Also make sure this is the first line of your Python file that has the logging statement:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

If that doesn't work, then I suspect that app engine logging does not support unicode.

Comment: I still get "Ã³" instead a "ó". I agree with you, using non-ascii characters is swallowing a lot of my time.

Comment: My first two lines are something like this:     `# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-   
#!/usr/bin/env python`.    I guess is the same and works for a lot of matters except this